# Android: How to get ListView is in scrolling mode or not?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

If my ListView will not in scrolling mode (because of few items on screen) then i want it `android:stackFromBottom="false"` but if my Listview started scroll(enough items to scroll) then i want `android:stackFromBottom="true"` through my code. How can i over come?Hope you will get me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare [`getLastVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29) with [`getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getCount%28%29) in a Runnable to see if the entire ListView fits on the screen as soon as it has been drawn. You should also check to see if the last visible row fits entirely on the screen.

Create the Runnable:

```
ListView listView;
Runnable fitsOnScreen = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int last = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
        if(last == listView.getCount() - 1 && listView.getChildAt(last).getBottom() <= listView.getHeight()) {
            // It fits!
        }
        else {
            // It doesn't fit...
        }
    }
};
```

In `onCreate()` queue your Runnable in the ListView's Handler:

```
listView.post(fitsOnScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

An [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) can give you the scrolling state of a `ListView`. The scroll state can be FLING, IDLE or TOUCH_SCROLL. In your case use the following (psuedo):

```
onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState){
     listView.setStackFromBottom(scrollState != OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
}
```